# Ambiguity about principle of excluded middle

Tags: logic

According to the principle of excluded middle, every statement is either true or false.

It might sound a little ridiculous, but consider the following statement:

> Mountains believe in God.

Believing in God has no meaning for things and beings that do not have intelligence. So what truth value should be determined for the above statement?

This was just an example.  In general, what truth value should be determined for such statements that say something about something that has no meaning for it?

Other examples can be:

> God is tall.

> Souls are bald.

Etc.

Comment: If the expression has no meaning, it is not a [*statement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(logic)).

Comment: I would argue that already the meaning of "Muslims/Christians/Jews believe in God" is unclear and it's questionable whether a truth value should be assigned to such a sentence. :-)

Comment: It seems to me that classical propositional logic is applicable only for propositions/statements that are unambiguously either  true or false. Whether a mountain believes in God, to use your example, is not unambiguously either true or false. So, we cannot use "Mount Everest does not believe in God" in any logical analysis based on classical propositional logic.

Comment: Principle of Excluded middle only makes sense if we have restrictions on the kinds of statements allowed. This is usually done by only allowing propositional statments, which by definition express something with is either true or false. So   x + 1 = 2 is a propositional sentence, x + 1 is not a propositional sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given statement to be a mathematical statement, it must be well defined.  Mathematics studies things in a different way than physics and other sciences.  When we say about something that it is true or false, we refer it to the raw statements that can be determined, or the axioms in which we believe.  We don't care what reality is.  Our reference is only thinking and logic.

Consider your question "Do mountains believe in God" What mathematics can do is rely on basic axioms and logic we can start by asking if belief requires thinking and awareness and if we agree that yes it is then we can ask if mountains  think and realize?  If we agree that no, then the answer that mathematical logic tells you is that the mountains do not believe in God and at the same time do not deny the existence of God, but note that it is not possible logically to verify the correctness or incorrectness of the statements that we agreed on, which is necessary to give any answer to  Absolutely, because mountains are not mathematical objects, and therefore answering this question logically may be a waste of time, it would be better to respect the range in which mathematics can work "questions expressing clearly defined objects", for the question of whether bald souls is also  A question that mathematics cannot answer, although the definition of the concept of baldness is mathematically possible (the bald is the one who has no hair on his head), so the problem of defining hair, as well as the problem of defining the head, and the problem of defining the soul, are all things that are not logically defined, but let me  I assume you are trying to answer a purely logical mathematical question and not these questions.

Let's start by choosing examples from mathematics:

0.5 even or odd?
Answer: Even and odd numbers do not represent all numbers, so the principle of the excluded middle does not work here.  There are numbers that are neither even nor odd, and the number 0.5 is one of them.  We see the same thing happen when we ask whether zero is positive or negative, or which is greater 2 + 2 or 1 + 3. An answer with one of the given possibilities is not possible in the first place, the question is simply wrong.

Let's choose another type of question, is positive zero (the absolute smallest positive number) rational or irrational?  Although its definition is understandable and the definition of rational number and irrational number is well defined, we do not have sufficient tools to answer this question.

Let's choose a third type of question, is 5 a concave-convex number?  Answer: Convexity and concavity are characteristic of shapes.  The question must be asked first: does the number have a form?  Then, if the answer is yes, we must know the shape of the number 5 in order to be able to determine whether it is convex or concave.  If the answer is no, then the number 5 does not carry either characteristic.

```
Is the center of the triangle that Pythagoras was studying on the principle of coordinates?  Pythagoras did not know coordinate systems, so for him, your question has no meaning for him, he cannot understand it, and he cannot judge it, although now we can say that Pythagoras was dealing with triangle 3, 4, 5 in any position,  But if we did not know the principle of coordinates, we would not be able to answer this question
```

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Good answer +1. Another good example from mathematics, can be $5 \subset 9$; which is neither true nor false.

Comment: Actually in some formalisations of the natural numbers in set theory, the subset relation and the less than or equal you know for numbers are the same thing